# c# How To Insert Null Value Postgre D.B from DataRow

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying insert data row in values to PostgreSql database.
But, not insert null value.
Because, i'm gettin continuous an error

Help me please, thanks.

```
            foreach (DataRow row2 in dt.Rows)
            {
                poscmd.Connection = posconn;
                poscmd.CommandText = "insert into public.CBS_DMA_ICME_SUYU values('" + (row2["SICIL_NO"].ToString()) + "','" + (row2["SOZLESME_ID"].ToString())
                  + "','" + (row2["SOZLESME_NO"].ToString()) + "','" + (row2["ABONE_ID"].ToString()) + "','" + (row2["ABONE_NO"].ToString()) + "',"
                  + (row2["SAYAC_NO"].ToString()) + ",'" + (row2["ISLEM_TARIHI"].ToString()) + "','" + (row2["KAC_GUN_SONRA_OKUNDU"].ToString()) + "',"
                  + (row2["OKUMA_DONEMI"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + "," + (row2["TUKETIM"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + "," + (row2["TAHAKKUK"].ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + ")";
                poscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (NULL);`

Comment: use parameters - will properly prepare the values.  (also guards against sql injection)

Comment: As your recommend, i do not adapt.
Your show please adapt state.